# JavaScript multidimensional array with null value error

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a web server returning a string from an ajax call.
The string looks like this and I save it into a variable called 'dta':

```
['46','company 1'],['8','company 2'],['11','company 3']
```

Then, I eval the string to make an array called 'ret'

```
ret=eval("[" + dta.split(",") + "]");
```

My problem is that if the array has a null value, it errors.
for example:

```
['46','company 1'],['8','company 2'],['11','']
```

Does JavaScript not allow null values in a multidimensional array, or is the problem
in the eval, or something else?

Comment: What is the desired output? It looks like your `eval` call might be superfluous, have you tried `JSON.parse(dta)`

Comment: Why not have the webserver return valid JSON instead ?

Comment: in javascript, that's an undefined value. null is an actual value "null". eval is not the right choice for a parser.

Comment: If it's already a string, why bother to split it if you're just going to immediately turn it back into a string?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T7tf7/

Comment: @adeneo Try running that on this input: `var dta = "['46','He says \"hello\"'],['8','company 2']";`

Comment: this has the desired effect:
`['46','company 1'],['8','company 2'],['11',null]`

Comment: @JLRishe - Or try running it on `var dta = '[unicorn's are "great/]'/"]'` or anything that isn't remotely related to the code posted in the question, and it fails. Strange !!

Comment: @Shawn Not that your approach is a good idea at all (it isn't), but can you show us a fiddle that reproduces the issue you're describing? If I execute this: `var dta = "['46','company 1'],['8','company 2'],['11','']"; eval("[" + dta.split(",") + "]");`, it produces an array just fine.

Comment: @adeneo A solution that only works without breaking for the narrow case of the example presented in the question isn't a very useful one. It doesn't take that much imagination to think that his data values might contain quotation marks. Your solution is overly simplistic.

Comment: @JLRishe - How do you build an accurate parser for invalid data that has no standard? The data is not really valid anything, hence my comment above, that the right approach would be to return JSON, a dataformat that can actually be parsed.

Comment: @adeneo I completely agree with your suggestion to have the server return JSON (and upvoted it), but it's pretty clear that the format he's trying to use is a comma-separated list of arrays of JavaScript strings. And it's perfectly reasonable to imagine that those strings could contain quotation marks (and this would still allow the strings to be valid JavaScript syntax that could be parsed with `eval()`). The malformed mess you presented as a counter-argument to my comment is a complete non-sequitur.

Comment: The server already escapes for special characters like quotation marks.

Comment: @jlrishe you are correct that normally an empty string works as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/JLhD9/1/ but for some reason the string coming from the web server doesn't. There must be additional character strings in the return like a chr$(0) or something.

Comment: what's odd is that at jsFiddle, if I replace '' with null it outputs the word "null". In my live code, if I use the word null in the string, it treats it like ''. Maybe it's not odd and that is by design but it seems odd to me.

Comment: @Shawn Is the server returning the data under your control and something you're able to modify? We may be able to figure out what's wrong with your setup, but adeneo is absolutely right that you should be working with standard JSON and not this ad-hoc stuff. As soon as you start using `eval()`, that's a pretty good sign that you're on the wrong track.

Comment: @JLRishe yes I have control of the server code. If I have to re-write it for JSON then I know how to do that. I was just trying to avoid re-writing old code (written by someone else). I just can't figure out why it was crapping out on an empty string.

Comment: ... and I know, I can hear my dad "if it's worth doing, it's worth doing right".....

Comment: One thing you can try is to loop through each character of the returned string and output each character and corresponding character code, to see if there's anything weird there. But I think this is one case where your dad would be right. :)